# Prove that $\Re \oint_\gamma \overline{ f(\zeta)}f'(\zeta)d\zeta=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is homolorphic in a open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{C}$. Why 
$$\Re \oint_\gamma \overline{ f(\zeta)}f'(\zeta)d\zeta=0\ ?$$
with $\gamma$ a closed curve in $\Omega$

This is my reasoning:
$$\Re \oint_\gamma \overline{ f(\zeta)}f'(\zeta)d\zeta=\oint_\gamma \Re \Big(\overline{ f(\zeta)}f'(\zeta)\Big) d\zeta$$
If we denote $f:=u+iv:\Omega \to\mathbb{C}$ it's easy to prove that:
$$\oint_\gamma \Re \Big(\overline{ f(\zeta)}f'(\zeta)\Big) d\zeta=\oint_\gamma u(\zeta)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\zeta)d\zeta +\oint_\gamma v(\zeta)\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(\zeta)d\zeta $$
I think that we can apply some theorem of real analysis. Any hint?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you tell a couple of the ways you tried? That helps judging what you know and what kind of answer would help you.

Comment: Pretty much the same question as asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199917/suppose-that-f-is-analytic-on-a-close-curve-%CE%B3-prove-or-disprove-int-gamma?rq=1).

Comment: Consider the derivative of $\left|f(z)\right|^2$