# $S$ is domain(open set and connected) and $\gamma$ is closed curve in $S$ . If $f(z)$ analytic on $S$ and $f'(z)$ continous on $S$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

$S$ is domain(open set and connected) and $\gamma$ is closed curve in $S$ . If $f(z)$ analytic on $S$ and $f'(z)$ continous on $S$ . Show that $\int _\gamma \overline{f(z)}f'(z) dz$ is only imajiner part

I stuck to prove that the real part is zero -__-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppose that $f$ is analytic on a close curve γ. Prove or disprove $\int_\gamma \overline{f(z)}f'(z)dz$ is purely imagine.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199917/suppose-that-f-is-analytic-on-a-close-curve-%ce%b3-prove-or-disprove-int-gamma)

Comment: Thank you for your information